# batch renaming of files with perl expressions

Tags: regex, bash, perl, batch-file, rename

This should be a basic question for a lot of people, but I am a biologist with no programming background, so please excuse my question.

What I am trying to do is rename about 100,000 gzipped data files that have existing name of a code (example: XG453834.fasta.gz).  I'd like to name them to something easily readable and parseable by me (example: Xanthomonas_galactus_str_453.fasta.gz).

I've tried to use `sed`, `rename`, and `mmv`, to no avail.  If I use any of those commands on a one-off script then they work fine, it's just when I try to incorporate variables into a shell script do I run into problems.  I'm not getting any errors, just no names are changed, so I suspect it's an I/O error.

Here's what my files look like:

```
#! /bin/bash
# change a bunch of file names
file=names.txt

while IFS=' '  read -r r1 r2;
do
    mmv ''$r1'.fasta.gz' ''$r2'.fasta.gz'
    # or I tried many versions of: sed -i 's/"$r1"/"$r2"/' *.gz
    # and I tried many versions of: rename -i 's/$r1/$r2/' *.gz

done < "$file"
```

...and here's the first lines of my txt file with single space delimiter:

```
    cat names.txt

   #find #replace 
   code1 name1
   code2 name2
   code3 name3
```

I know I can do this with python or perl, but since I'm stuck here working on this particular script I want to find a simple solution to fixing this bash script and figure out what I am doing wrong.  Thanks so much for any help possible.

Also, I tried to `cat` the names file (see comment from Ashoka Lella below) and then use `awk` to move/rename.  Some of the files have variable names (but will always start with the code), so I am looking for a find & replace option to just replace the "code" with the "name" and preserve the file name structure.

I suspect I am not escaping the variable within the single tick of the perl expression, but I have poured over a lot of manuals and I can't find the way to do this.

Comment: All of the answers would work for the examples you have provided. If your filenames are more complex in reality (i.e. they contain spaces/special characters, then you should edit your question to show some examples that better represent the situation. If you require more complex logic (conditional renaming, pattern matching, etc.) then you should make that clear, showing some examples of the desired behaviour in the question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Tom, I do appreciate it.  Looks like most of my issues are with non-conforming "codes" which when apparently spaced out randomly across a few thousand data files make this a less direct answer.  I'm probably going to try to address this with a python script, but I was hoping for something more simple.  Thanks again for helping me learn a better way to do this!

Answer (score 3):

If you're absolutely sure than the filenames **doesn't contain spaces** of tabs, you can try the next

```
xargs -n2 < names.txt echo mv
```

This is for DRY run (will only print what will do) - if you satisfied with the result, remove the `echo` ...

If you want check the existence ot the target, use

```
xargs -n2 < names.txt echo mv -i
```

if you want NEVER allow overwriting of the target use

```
xargs -n2 < names.txt echo mv -n
```

again, remove the `echo` if youre satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you need to be using `mmv`, a simple `mv` will do. Also, there's no need to specify the `IFS`, the default will work for you:

```
while read -r src dest; do mv "$src" "$dest"; done < names.txt
```

I have double quoted the variable names as it is generally considered good practice but in this case, a space in either of the filenames will result in `read` not working as you expect.

You can put an `echo` before the `mv` inside the loop to ensure that the correct command will be executed.

Note that in your file `names.txt`, the `.fasta.gz` suffix is already included, so you shouldn't be adding it inside the loop aswell. Perhaps that was your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should rename all files in column1 to column2 of names.txt. Provided they are in the same folder as names.txt

```
cat names.txt| awk '{print "mv "$1" "$2}'|sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I tried this already (should have been clearer above, I will edit) and this works on about half of the data file names, but some of are being piped to me with variable names, but which start with the code designation, therefore I am looking for a more find & replace (versus a rename) function.  Looks like I should dust off the python book -- it would be good practice for me.  Thanks again!