# Is there a way to find files, move and rename if needed in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a folder and who has subfolders. Inside them i have .c, .cc, .ccp and .cxx files. I am trying to use

```
find ~/dir2 -iregex '.*\.\(c\|cc\|ccp\|cxx\)$' -exec mv -i '{}' ~/destination \;
```

but it is asking me if i want to overwrite files so if i agree i am losing some files. I want to rename files with the same name and then move them. Any ideas?

Comment: Write a script that checks if the destination file already exists, and renames it first. Then you can run that script from `-exec`.

Comment: Because this is a part of a script, there is no other way to do it without second script?

Comment: Use `-print` instead of `-exec`, then pipe it to a `while read -r filename` loop that does what you want.

Comment: @Barmar i didnt get it..i am new to bash. I would be much appreciated if you could explain a bit. Thanks anyway

Comment: `find ... -print | while read -r filename; do ...; done`

Comment: The code in `...` checks if the file already exists in the destination directory, renames it, and then moves `$filename` to the destination.

Comment: I hope that's enough for you to understand, and you're not expecting us to write the script for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch renaming of files with perl expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711833/batch-renaming-of-files-with-perl-expressions)